# Window.xaml "cannot be edited in the design view" after moving to Windows 10

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

After changing Windows to Windows 10, I am faced with this error in all of my C# projects that use WPF :

> Window.xaml cannot be edited in the design view

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: Generally speaking, just avoid using the designer. Handcrafted XAML will always be better anyways.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET That is terrible advice.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Really? Sounds like a good discussion topic for the WPF room if you really want to go there. I *never* user the designer except as a rough check that my XAML produces the correct layout

Comment: I'm with @BradleyDotNET.  Although it is the wrong answer it's the best solution.  I quit using the designer when I switched to XAML because the markup is just easier to use.  It's nice to get a visual after it's said and done but because of the dynamic characteristics and just how XAML is written / loaded it's rarely dependable.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Clean and rebuild your solution.

See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8d13959e-90e8-4b25-9b5b-a5e7f8dd3ef2/windowxaml-cannot-be-edited-in-design-view?forum=wpf) for additional help.

Comment: Funnily enough this happened to me today, I had to clean all and then reboot to fix it. If that still doesn't work then you'll need to show us the corresponding .cs file, and maybe re-post the xaml file you've already posted at a resolution high enough for us to actually read the text.

Comment: I fixed it. I updated visual studio and  that problem fixed .

Answer (score -2):

You could be opening a Blank App (Universal windows 8.1) instead of as a Windows Form Application.